# How to add action in then section of cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

I'm new to cucumber and I wonder how can I test the following scenario:

- user, that is not signed in, clicks on "buy" link on my site
- popup with login/passwords shows
- user fills login and password fields and then click 'Sign in'
- page reloads
- user clicks again on "buy" link and see popup with order details

I have problem with defining "Then" section, because for me it should be:

```
Then
  When I click "buy"
  I should see "order details"
```

Is this possible with cucumber?

Answer (score 1):

Scenario should have a single testing goal. With your current scenario you have 2 goals so it may be better to write 2 scenarios:

1. Possibility of login after clicking buy
2. Ability to see order details after clicking buy.

I don't understand why you want to do this using 1 scenario.

---

That said, Cucumber doesn't distinguish between Given, When and Then at step definition layer so you can write like this:

```
Given ...
When ...
Then ...
When ...
Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature file would look like this (simplified):

```
Feature: View Order Details
  As a user I can process an order

  Scenario: Process Online Order
    Given I am logged in
    When I click "buy"
    Then I should see the order details
```